# HAProxy: how to read headers in https connection?

Tags: reverse-proxy, https, haproxy

I want to configure haproxy in order to balance between two backend servers. I have simple configuration

```
global
log /dev/log    local0
log /dev/log    local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
stats timeout 30s
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon

defaults
 log global
 option httplog
 option dontlognull
 mode http
 timeout connect 5000ms
 timeout client 50000ms
 timeout server 50000ms

frontend my_frontend
 bind *:8000
 default_backend my_backend
 http-request capture req.hdr(user_id) len 64

backend my_backend
 #simple proxy servers (squid)
 server serv1 1.2.3.4:8001
 server serv2 5.6.7.8:8001
 stick-table type string size 20m expire 1m
 stick on hdr(user_id)
 balance hdr(user_id)
```

Then I request to haproxy with `curl`

```
curl --proxy my_haproxy_public_ip:8000 --header "user_id:test42" https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

This configuration works fine in http connections (I can see captured header in logs), but headers are not visible in https connections and that's why balancing is not possible. I am a newbie in connections and protocols, and possibly missing something. Is it a way to fetch any headers from https requests to enable balancing with `hdr(my_header)`?

Comment: You need to terminate TLS at haproxy.

Comment: It might be helpful.  As I use haproxy inputs in local secured network it's okay to pass http trafic on haproxy  frontend. Is it possible to change the scheme (protocol) from http to https in backend block? My backend is transparent squid proxy that proxies requests to the outer world @michael-hampton

Comment: haproxy is a _reverse_ proxy. It will not do this. You need a _forward_ proxy for reaching arbitrary websites. Use squid with SSL bump.

Comment: So, I need to achieve such scheme: http request to haproxy - haproxy - http request to one of squids servers - translate http to https - target site. Am I right? @michael-hampton

Comment: No, you don't use haproxy anywhere. You get rid of it.

Comment: Okay, but my aim is to balance requests between multiple squid servers to hide my single client ip adress behind multiple nodes (and ip addresses as a result). @michael-hampton

Comment: Purporse is to balance requests from single static ip address between multiple squid nodes (and ip addresses as result). But this ip address is used by multiple users. And I need to do it in a sticky-session manner, that is why I need access to http headers in haproxy balancer.@michael-hampton